# C++ Releasing memory after struct initialise?

Tags: c++, struct, free

I'm creating my_data this way. Should I manually free the memory at the end of program? If yes how do do that? free() gives me conversion err, and delete() wants pointer.

```
struct data{
    int a;
    int b;

    data():
        a(1),
        b(2) {}
} my_data;
```

Comment: You should manually `delete` memory if you manually `new` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should not.

You are not creating the structure on the heap, so there is no need to release the memory manually. The memory will be marked as available to the OS at the end of the program.

And don't even think of doing `delete &my_data`, as you'd almost sure get a sefgault as the memory is being released twice.

You'd need to if using dynamic allocation such as

```
data* pdata = new data; // needs delete pdata
```

Comment: How can you tell it is "on the stack" without seeing any context?

Comment: @AnT he's declaring the variable: `struct data{...} my_data; // declaration`. Here `my_data` is of type `struct data`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @vsoftco: I can see that he's declaring a variable. But this variable will only be "on the stack" if declared locally, inside a block. This  same variable will end up in static memory (which is not "on the stack") if declared in namespace scope. Yet you claim that it is "on the stack". How do you know? Without seeing the surrounding context it is not possible to say where this variable is declared.

Comment: In fact, local class declarations (with variable or without it) are rare in beginner's code. I would guess that there is a better chance that this declaration resides in namespace scope. In that case the variable is in global static memory, not "on the stack".

Comment: @AnT, thanks, good point. Will remove the "on the stack", although it is definitely not "on the heap".